# PCRE pattern that validates more than I wants

Tags: regex, expression, pcre

In order to develop a routing module for a Web app, I have to make intensive use of regular expressions.
I have to test URIs of the form:

```
/Services/service_name/List/of/Parameters/or/nothing
```

The service name is mandatory, but not the end of the line parameters.
The line can either end with a slash or not.
In addition to alphanumeric characters, parameters can only contain the special characters `-` and `_`.

Here the expression in question:

```
(?:\/Services\/(?'var'[[:alnum:]_-]+)|\G(?!\A))(?:\/(?'params'[[:alnum:]_-]+))?
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/lB7nL8/1)

You see that if we add `+` at the end of the chain it is still be valid while it should not be.

Comment: Excuse me, but what is the issue here? `var` and `param`s are captured alright.

Comment: where are you adding the `+`? in the test string or the regex?

Comment: It should capture the values only if the whole chain is valid.
So **/Services/Test/Ok/Boo/Test** or **/Services/Test/Ok/Boo/Test/** must be valid while **/Services/Test/Ok/Boo/Test+** or **/Services/Test/Ok/Boo/Test//**must be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the string to match if only it ends with a slash or an alphanumeric using a positive look-ahead `(?=.*(?:\/|[[:alnum:]_-])$)` at the beginning:

```
(?=.*(?:\/|[[:alnum:]_-])$)(?:\/Services\/(?'var'[[:alnum:]_-]+)|(?<!^)\G)\/(?:(?'params'[[:alnum:]_-]+))?
```

Note I am using multiline mode assuming you have these strings as separate entities.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ6bC3/2)

Comment: Thanks you, with just a tweak and it's exactly what I want.


`(?=.*(?:\/|[[:alnum:]_-])$)(?:\/Services\/(?'var'[[:alnum:]_-]+)|\G(?!\A))(?:\/(?'params'[[:alnum:]_-]+))?`

Comment: This may be someone who realized that an error existed in this solution :

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ6bC3/5)

Someone on [developpez.com](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1520839/php/langage/regex/pattern-pcre-non-exclusif/) provided me another solution a little more optimized :

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/pX4xD2/4)

All this made me learn a lot more about regex.